# Why does Google Chrome require you to have admin access to be set as the default browser?

Tags: google-chrome

Neither Firefox nor Internet Explorer requires admin to set as default. Why does Chrome require it?

Comment: What basis are you making this under?  That was not my experience, and I have reinstalled it numerous times over the few years I have used it.

Comment: The simple answer is that Chrome installs in such a way where the profile is NOT connected to the user.  Firefox actually requires proper permissions to be installed as a normal User, because the Firefox profile, is connected to the User profile itself.  What is the purpose of this question?  **If you are trying to block this behavior there are better ways to prevent it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to associate file-types and protocols with a program. For something complex like a web-browser which can support several file-types and several protocols, there are numerous settings that have to assigned to make it the default browser. Worse, there are numerous other hooks into the system that a browser can set these days such as making a buttons in the Start menu, shortcuts in the taskbar, integrating with the shell and email clients, and so on.

So there are quite a lot of different settings to be modified, mostly in the registry, a few in the file-system. Some are mandatory (e.g., `http` protocol, `.url` shortcuts, `.html` files, etc.), but others are optional. As a result, some browsers will set some which others don’t (few, if any, configure set every single possible setting).

Some of these numerous settings are in user-accessible places while others are in areas that require higher privileges.

In addition, Windows essentially duplicates a lot of things on a system-level and a user-level. For example, you can set some things to apply to individual users or to the whole system (or both). Not surprisingly, changing a system-level setting will require administrator permissions.

Obviously Chrome configures some settings that require extra privileges and/or modifies both the user and system versions of some settings.

Comment: If you want to know *specifically* which privileged values it sets, then you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to observe what file and registry changes it makes when you click the *Make default* button.